# Why I cannot print this list?

Tags: c#, web-services

It is my first time to deal with web services. I am a new C# developer and I am trying to retrieve the user information from the web services. I could be able to connect to the web service and retrieve the information. Now, I am trying to print a list of the users under different levels in the company. The problem I am getting this kind of error and I don't know:
***foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UserLib.UserDate' because 'UserLib.UserData' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.***

I have Class Library project named UserLib and I have two classes within it.

**UserData Class code:**

```
namespace UserLib
{
    public class UserData
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string fullName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string jobTitle { get; set; }
        public string levelCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**GetUserData Class code:**

```
namespace UserLib
{
    public class GetUserData
    {
        public UserData getUserData(string login)
        {

            var dat = new UserData //UserData object
            {
                username = response.Username,
                fullName = response.FullName,
                email = response.Email,
                jobTitle = response.Title,
                levelCode = levelCode,
                           };
            return dat;
        }
    }
}
```

Program Class code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the username: ");
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        Console.Write("Username: ");
                        var login = Console.ReadLine();

                            var getUser = new GetUserData();
                            var dat = getUser.getUserData(login);  // <== class library call

                            Console.WriteLine("Username:   " + dat.username);
                            Console.WriteLine("Full Name:   " + dat.fullName);
                            Console.WriteLine("Email:   " + dat.email);
                            Console.WriteLine("Job Title:   " + dat.jobTitle);
                            Console.WriteLine("Level Code:   " + dat.levelCode);
                            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                            printAll(login);
}
```

**Could you please tell me how to fix this and print this list of users?**

Comment: I do not see a list anywhere... I see the getUserData method returning only a single object which does not implement IEnumerable. Why are you doing a foreach on it ?

Answer (score 2):

`UserData` isn't an `IEnumerable` like `List<UserData>`, it is just an object. 
You need a method `getUsersData` that returns an `IEnumerable<UserData>`

Um also.. your `switch` looks redundant.

The first `case` cascades to the second `case`.. the second `case` does the same as the third.. 
So why not just have `output.Add(users.userName);`

Assuming the real code is what you pasted.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of modifying it in order to be able to retrun a single value and list at the same time?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that.. but the simple answer is to wrap the return values in another class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getUserData` method doesn't return a list of users, it returns a single `UserData` (the details for one user), therefore you can't expect to iterate over this return value as if it were a collection.

On another note, use PascalCase for method names and your property names on `UserData`.